# The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing - SQL problem Select clause

Tags: sql, vba, odbc

Please could someone look into my code? This SQL statement is a part of VBA code related to ODBC connection. I received error during inputting data from other excel file to the active sheet.

> The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

My SQL query:

```
SQL = "SELECT [Data$].[Dim#]+ IIF([Data From System$].[Data Dim#] IS NULL,[Data From System$].[Data Dim#]) AS [Value], XYZ, [Data$].[Dim#], [Data$].[X], [Data$].[Y], [Data$].[Dim2], [Data#].[Dim3], " & _
    "[Data$].[Dim4], [Data$].[Dim5], [Data$].[Dim6], [Data$].[Dim7], [Data$].[Dim8], [Data$].[Dim9], " & _
    "[Data From System$].[XX], [Data From System$].[XX1], [Data From System$].[XX2],  [Data From System$].[X X], [Data From System$].[Dim#], 'XYZ' AS XYZ " & _
    "FROM [Data$] LEFT OUTER JOIN [Data From System$] ON [Data$].[Dim#] = [Data From System$].[Dim#]"
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible problem is this:

```
IIF([Data From System$].[Data Dim#] IS NULL,
    [Data From System$].[Data Dim#]
   ) AS [Value]
```

`IIF()` is a bespoke function for SQL Server and MS Access.  I think it requires three arguments.  The logic here seems quite strange (returning `NULL` when the value is `NULL`).  You probably intend `COALESCE()` or `NZ()`.